# Can't exit and strange order of execution with tee

Tags: bash, tee

I am getting some strange behavior when piping the output of a function to the `tee` command. The first problem is that I can't exit the program when using the `exit` command when called from a function piped to `tee`. For Example:

```
myfunction(){
    # Some stuff here
    exit 1
}

myfunction | tee -a $UPGRADE_LOG
```

When I run the above code, the program fails to exit and runs to completion.

The other issue I am having is that `tee` seems to have cause some code to run in such a way that the sequential order is undone. I have the following output:

```
SHOWING SYSTEM-WIDE AND INSTATNCE MEMORY USAGE:
Are you sure you would like to back up the instance given current memory contraints? [y/n]: Filesystem                           Size   Used  Avail  Use%  Mounted on
/dev/mapper/system-root              15G    13G   1.5G   90%   /
Log File Size: 24K   Total Size to Package: 248K Available Space: 1.5G
```

When it should run as:

```
SHOWING SYSTEM-WIDE AND INSTATNCE MEMORY USAGE:
Filesystem                           Size   Used  Avail  Use%  Mounted on
/dev/mapper/system-root              15G    13G   1.5G   90%   /
Log File Size: 24K   Total Size to Package: 248K Available Space: 1.5G
Are you sure you would like to back up the instance given current memory contraints? [y/n]:
```

Things work properly when not using `tee`. The issues seem to be related to one another. Any ideas why this is the case and what I should do about it?

Comment: Please don't ask multiple questions instead split them. Note also that you increase your chances of getting good answers if you come as close as possible to a MCVE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: These questions seem to be linked to the same issue, so I put them together. Sorry if it brought about any confusion.

Comment: No, the code doesn't *run* non-sequentially -- what happens is that your stdout and stderr are going through different processes so they arrive at different times. The original writes still happen at the same time, though.

Comment: Yeah I knew the code ran sequentially. I was just pointing out that it *behaved* as such. I assumed this was because they were running separately, I just wasn't sure why. Thanks for the clarifications!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[kvantour's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52837860/14122) tells you why this happens. This one tells you how to fix it. :)

```
with_logs_piped() {
  local logfile=$1; shift
  "$@" > >(tee -a -- "$logfile") 2>&1  # 2>&1 redirects stderr through the same tee so it's
}                                      # ...also logged, and shows up sync'd with stdout.

myfunction() {
    # Some stuff here
    exit 1
}

with_logs_piped "$UPGRADE_LOG" myfunction
```

What's important here is that instead of using a regular pipeline, we're using a [process substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst) for `tee` -- so `myfunction` runs in your shell itself, not a subshell, so the `exit` applies properly.

---

As for why redirecting stdout through `tee` desynchronizes stderr, see [Separately redirecting and recombining stderr/stdout without losing ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45760692/separately-redirecting-and-recombining-stderr-stdout-without-losing-ordering)

Comment: This solution is working perfectly. Thanks for the explanation as well!

Answer (score 1):

The `exit` statement exits the (sub-)shell the process is running in. Now here comes the surprise:

> **Pipelines**
>
> A pipeline is a sequence of one or more commands separated by one of the control operators `|` or `|&`.  The format for a pipeline is:
>
> ```
> [time [-p]] [ ! ] command [ [|⎪|&] command2 ... ]
> ```
>
> <snip>
>
> **Each command in a pipeline is executed as a separate process (i.e., in a subshell).**
>
> **<sub>source: `man bash`</sub>**

So, the `exit` statement from the function just kills the subshell of the pipeline. This actually means that `exit` does nothing in a pipeline

```
$ exit | exit | echo foo
foo
$ exit | exit
$ # shell not terminated
```

**Note:** this is clearly shell dependent because [zsh](/questions/tagged/zsh) behaves differently.

Comment: "Does nothing" isn't *quite* accurate; `exit 2 | exit 3 | true` sets `${PIPESTATUS[0]}` to 2 and `${PIPESTATUS[1]}` to 3, and if `set -o pipefail` were active, would cause the pipeline as a whole to have an exit status of 3. Granted, though, that those effects aren't what the OP wanted. :)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy True. Also if the option `lastpipe` is set, it will have an effect on the last `exit` statement (in the eg. `exit | exit`)