# Record Bash Interaction, saving STDIN, STDOUT seperately

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, interaction

So I want to record my bash interaction, which I know I can do with [script](https://linux.die.net/man/1/script), or [ttyrec](https://github.com/mjording/ttyrec). Except I want one feature more than they have. Save input (i.e STDIN), and output (i.e. STDOUT) separately.

So something like (where I typed the first "Hello World!"), except of course `script` takes one `[file]` arg, not two:

```
user@pc:~$ script input.txt output.txt
Script started
user@pc:~$ paste > textfile.txt
Hello World!
user@pc:~$ cat textfile.txt 
Hello World!
user@pc:~$ exit
Script done
```

So `input.txt` looks like:

```
user@pc:~$ paste > textfile.txt
Hello World!
user@pc:~$ cat textfile.txt 
user@pc:~$ exit
```

And `output.txt` looks like:

```
Hello World!
exit
```

So I want a program like `script` which saves STDIN & STDOUT separately. Since currently, this would be the normal output of `script` (which I do not want, and need seperated):

```
Script started

user@pc:~$ paste > textfile.txt
Hello World!
user@pc:~$ cat textfile.txt 
Hello World!
user@pc:~$ exit
exit

Script done
```

Does this exist, or is this possible?

Note the usage of `paste` command, since I had considered filtering the ouput file based on `user@pc:~$`, but in my case (as with `paste`) this would not work.

Comment: If you want the prompts in `input.txt` as well, be aware that the shell prints the prompt to standard error, and it may be difficult to separate the prompt from text that other programs write to standard error.

Comment: You would have to put something between stdin and the shell. Something like `cat | tee input.txt | sh -i | tee output.txt`.

Comment: Saving stdin and stdout separately is trivial (*slightly* tricky if you want to retain TTY-ness, in which case you'd want to instrument `screen` or `tmux` or the like, but generally: put one `tee` on each side and you're done). Saving stdout and stderr separately without losing ordering is damned hard (and requires the class of tool discussed in jhnc's answer or my comment thereto).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## empty

[empty](http://empty.sourceforge.net/) is packaged for various linux distributions (it is `empty-expect` on ubuntu).

1. open two terminals
2. **terminal 1** : run `empty -f -i in.fifo -o out.fifo bash`
3. **terminal 1** : run `tee stdout.log <out.fifo`
4. **terminal 2** : run `stty -icanon -isig eol \001; tee stdin.log >in.fifo`
5. type commands into **terminal 2**, watch the output in **terminal 1**

   - fix terminal settings with `stty icanon isig -echo`
   - log stderr separately from stdout with `exec 2>stderr.log`
   - when finished, `exit` the bash shell; both `tee` commands will quit
6. `stdout.log` and `stdin.log` contain the logs

---

Some other options:

## peekfd

You could try `peekfd` (part of the `psmisc` package). It probably needs to be run as root:

```
peekfd -c pid fd fd ... > logfile
```

where pid is the process to attach to, `-c` says to attach to children too, and `fd` are list of file descriptors to watch (basically `0`, `1`, `2`). There are various other options to tweak the output.

The logfile will need postprocessing to match your requirements.

## SystemTap and similar

Over on [unix stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/281319/tool-to-watch-other-ttys-for-linux/281432#281432), use of the [SystemTap](https://sourceware.org/systemtap/) tool has been proposed.
However, it is not trivial to configure and you'll still have to write a module that separates stdin and stdout.

[sysdig](https://github.com/draios/sysdig) and [bpftrace](http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2018-10-08/dtrace-for-linux-2018.html) also look interesting.

## LD_PRELOAD / strace / ltrace

Using [LD_PRELOAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426230/what-is-the-ld-preload-trick), you can wrap lowlevel calls such as write(2).

You can run your shell under `strace` or `ltrace` and record data passed to system and library functions (such as write). Lots of postprocessing needed:

```
ltrace -f -o ltrace.log -s 10000000000 -e write bash
```

## patch ttyrec

ttyrec.c is only 500 lines of fairly straightforward code and looks like it would be fairly easy to patch to use multiple logfiles.

Comment: FYI, I've implemented a closely related tool (tracking stdout/stderr distinctly with ordering retained) on top of sysdig here on this site; see [Separately redirecting and recombining stderr/stdout without losing ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45760692/separately-redirecting-and-recombining-stderr-stdout-without-losing-ordering). Didn't include timing data there, but just retaining the original sysdig trace would have the effect.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Nice. I gave up on systemtap as ubuntu's packages don't play well with secure boot. Hadn't come across sysdig but it is offering to enroll a new MOK so I'm going to reboot and have a play...

Comment: Awesome answer! So I went with the last option, making a patch (for script), although in a basic way. So it outputs special characters for the different streams, then RegEx the output into different files afterwards. Messy - but it worked! Thanks!