# How to unify stdout and stderr, yet be able to distinguish between them?

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout, stderr

I'd like to produce a readable HTML report of a process run. Towards that end, I'd like to track both `stdout` and `stderr`, and output them interleaved, yet distinguished - for example, the log will show them both combined according to the order they were emitted, but with `stdout` in black and `stderr` in bold red.

I can readily see a solution that will keep them distinguished: just redirect each to `subprocess.PIPE`. Of course, then they can't be recombined in order. It's also easy to unify them in order: just redirect `stderr` to `subprocess.STDOUT`. However, then they will be indistinguishable.

Thus getting the outputs to be *either* distinguished *or* combined in order is straightforward, but getting both is not.

What's the way to do that in Python?

Comment: I would just wrap stdout and stderr in different `<span>` classes as I produce the output

Comment: @NullUserException sure, but how do you keep them in order, yet distinguished?  I can either redirect both to `subprocess.PIPE`, in which case they'd be distinguished but separate, or I can redirect `stderr` to `stdout`, in which case they will be unified but not distinguished.

Comment: You *can't* retain perfect order while distinguishing them. UNIX doesn't provide the guarantees necessary to make it possible. It's possible to get close, sure, but to have a guarantee that what you have is perfect, you need to use a syscall-monitoring mechanism to reconstruct the writes.

Comment: It's tagged bash rather than python, but everything discussed in [Separately redirecting and recombining stdout/stderr without losing ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45760692/separately-redirecting-and-recombining-stderr-stdout-without-losing-ordering) applies.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy fair point, but how do I get as close as possible?  I know this can be done since if I redirect `stderr` to `stdout` on the shell, I get the unified output in "good enough" order.

Comment: You actually get *perfect* order when you do that on the shell, just the same as you do in Python when you use `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT`, but that doesn't "keep them distinguished".

Comment: ...anyhow, if you want to try to get something as good as you can get -- have a separate thread reading each FD and handling its content as it's received, with the program doing the writes configured in unbuffered or line-buffered mode (how to do that is tool-specific, though on GNU platforms there's `stdbuf`, which will work if the program is sticking with glibc-provided defaults for its output buffering).

Comment: ...running `2>&1` on the shell (or the Python high-level equivalent) duplicates the file descriptors, making FD 2 *point to the same kernelspace object* as FD 1, so the writes are well-ordered, but also impossible to distinguish between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `select()` to multiplex the output.  Suppose you have stdout and stderr being captured in pipes, this code will work:

```
import select
import sys

inputs = set([pipe_stdout, pipe_stderr])

while inputs:
  readable, _, _ = select.select(inputs, [], [])
  for x in readable:
    line = x.readline()
    if len(line) == 0:
      inputs.discard(x)
    if x == pipe_stdout
      print 'STDOUT', line
    if x == pipe_stderr
      print 'STDERR', line
```

Comment: This is true, but it doesn't guarantee unmodified/original ordering. Try having a program that interleaves individual writes to stdout and stderr -- if it does those writes fast enough, you'll have clumps (`stdout`/`stdout`/`stderr`/`stderr`) rather than retaining the interleaved `stdout`/`stderr`/`stdout`/`stderr`.

Comment: Without the source program flushing, or modifying the source program to do the tagging, I think this is as good as one can get.

Comment: I agree; point I'm making is that the distinction (that "good as one can get" is not "perfect") should be made clear.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I think that's the best we can do, though. Any lack of order you'll get with Mark's solution is the same you'd get by redirecting `stderr` to `stdout` at the shell level as you proposed. So it seems to be the best possible solution.

Comment: @DunPeal, ...no, "same you'd get [...] at the shell level" is not true; redirecting stderr to stdout at the shell level gives you stronger guarantees (just as passing `stdout=subprocess.STDERR` to `subprocess.Popen` does), because when you do that the two FDs refer to the same underlying object, so there *does* exist a well-defined serialization between writes to them.

Comment: @DunPeal, ...that said, "best possible solution" *is* true, unless you're going to go as far as OS-level hackery to track the individual syscalls and reconstruct order from that. Which I've done, as a proof-of-concept on the above-linked bash question, but that's not actually a practice I'd advise people to deploy in production. :)